# How to know which line gives error in python?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am new to Python so please excuse my rudimentary question. 
When I get an error I can usually figure out what line caused the error, but sometimes from the error message itself I can't decide which line is responsible. So I add some messages between the lines to track the issue. Is there any more effective solution to that?
I am running my codes form ArcGIS toolbox script and I am not sure if I can trace the errors from there.

Comment: But tracebacks in Python include line numbers of the faulty lines.

Comment: Let me revise my question.

Comment: Print statements are a great way to find out what is going on when your code is executing.  If you are using Windows/Idle open the Stack Viewer from the shell window's Debug menu after the exception has stopped execution.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that my codes don't run under shell window and I get different calls. I can only run them through toolbox in Arcmap. For example when I run my code in shell window it doesn't recognize arcpy module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use `print` statements (okay, function in Py3). It's the most standard way. Just use it to track where are you now in your program, and what are you doing.

However, if your application processes a large data, or if it's a large application, `print` statements may be not enough. Sometimes, you'll need `try` and `except` statements, just to narrow the search of the error.

More on error handling? [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)!

[This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If youre trying to do this with a excepted error do this:

```
import traceback
import sys

try:
    raise Exception("foo")
except:
    for frame in traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2]):
        fname,lineno,fn,text = frame
        print "Error in %s on line %d" % (fname, lineno)
```

otherwise just read the traceback

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks very promising!